# nonlinearfitmodel, 3 parameters, max iterations = 10 million still not converging

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit a set of data to the expression to population in the excited state in a Rabi oscillation problem.

I am given # of states in ground and excited state, as well as detuning. I convert the # of states to a percentage, thus columns D (brought from kHz to Hz by multiplying by 1000 and converted to angular frequency by multiplying by 2 pi) and E of this table are my x and y values of "data"

[image]

```
data = {{0, 0.02363725}, {2 \[Pi] *4000, 0.17146772}, {2 \[Pi] *8000, 
0.13166519}, {2 \[Pi] *12000, 0.02235492}, {2 \[Pi] *16000, 
0.13261997}, {2 \[Pi] *20000, 0.60791461}, {2 \[Pi] *24000, 
0.90938007}, {2 \[Pi] *28000, 0.83125466}, {2 \[Pi] *32000, 
0.173583}, {2 \[Pi] *36000, 0.02294157}, {2 \[Pi] *40000, 
0.07752914}, {2 \[Pi] *44000, 0.16270294}, {2 \[Pi] *48000, 
0.00746117}, {2 \[Pi] *52000, 0.00486276}};
```

Then I try to use NonLinearFitModel to fit the data to the following expression for probability in the excited state:

$$P_e = \bigg(\frac{\omega_R}{\Omega_R}\bigg)^2 \sin^2\bigg(\frac{1}{2} \Omega_R t\bigg)$$

where $\Omega_R = \sqrt{\omega_R^2 + \delta^2}$

I use $\delta + \delta0$ because I am not fitting around the axis, and I plug in 70 microseconds for t because I am given the pulse lifetime of the laser.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (( wr)^2/Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2])^2 Sin[1/2 Sqrt[( wr)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2]70*10^-6]^2, {wr, \[Delta]0}, \[Delta]];
```

This fit is not accurate

[image]

A friend mentioned that with Python they did the fit for 3 parameters, t as well as $\omega_R$ and $\delta_0$ and they got back a matching fit curve AND the 70 microsecond value for t. I am unfamiliar with python so I tried extending what I have above to 3 parameters.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, (( wr)^2/Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2])^2 Sin[1/2 Sqrt[( wr)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2]t]^2, {wr, \[Delta]0, t}, \[Delta], MaxIterations -> 100000];
```

I keep getting the message that it cannot converge despite increasing the MaxIterations all the way up to 10,000,000 (last night, not here) and letting it run for a while.
[image]

Any advice on how to fit this data?

---

With Domen's advice, the fit improves

[image]

Comment: You are trying to fit a very complicated model, and finding the best parameters is not a trivial thing. Mathematica will usually begin by trying $\omega_r = 1$ and $\delta_0 = 1$, and then move on from here. It will find some local minimum, which can be far from the actual global minimum ("best fit"). Give it some help and provide it with _better initial guesses_! ``nlm = NonlinearModelFit[..., {{wr, 1000}, {\[Delta]0, -150000}}, \[Delta]];``

Comment: GREAT point. My fit improves with telling the function where to start looking for solutions, but it is not perfect. For reference, my friend gets a perfect looking fit with the parameters $\delta = 154620, \omega_R =49900, t=70 \mu s$

Comment: @Domen do feel free to submit that as an answer for the check mark :D

Comment: In your field is it standard for fit a model with Gaussian errors with a constant variance when the response variable is really a ratio of integer counts suggesting that a model with a binomial response would be more appropriate?  Certainly when the counts are large a continuous model can be useful but I would be concerned about the error structure maybe not being an adequate approximation of the sampling error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can guestimate the parameters really well.

You've said yourself that $\delta_0$ is your center point designated by the maximum in the data. Thus we can already read $\delta_0\approx-150kHz$.

You've also said, that the laser pulse with is about 70 microseconds. Lets also use this as an approximating starting value.

Finally,the $\omega_r$ seems to be a linewidth of the data of some kind. Lets guess the FWHM to be around $\approx 100kHz$. Thus $\omega_r\approx 50kHz$.

Lets plug this all into NonlinearModelFit:

```
model = ((wr/o)^2*Sin[o/2*t]^2) /. o -> Sqrt[wr^2 + (d + d0)^2]
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model, {{wr, 50000}, {t, 7*10^-5}, {d0, -150000}}, d];
```

Fitting perfectly:

[image]

Parameters:

$2\pi\times\delta_0=(-154.6\pm 1.2)kHz$

$t=(70.9\pm 2.2)\mu s$

$2\pi\times\omega_r=(50\pm 3)kHz$

Answer (score 4):

You need to play around with good starting values. I worked with this until it was looking reasonable

```
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
 Plot[Evaluate[((wr)^2/Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (δ + δ0)^2])^2 Sin[
       1/2 Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (δ + δ0)^2] 70*10^-6]^2 /. {wr \
-> 1.6 10^2, δ0 -> -1.717 10^5}], {δ, 0, 2 π 52000},
   PlotRange -> All],
 Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

By hand I changed the value of `wr` and `δ0`untill it looked close. Then I gave starting values to `NonlinearModelFit`. Returned instantly.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  data, ((wr)^2/Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (δ + δ0)^2])^2 Sin[
     1/2 Sqrt[(wr)^2 + (δ + δ0)^2] 70*10^-6]^2, {{wr, 
    1.6 10^2}, {δ0, -1.717 10^5}}, δ]
```

The plot gives

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data],
 Plot[nlm[\[Delta]], {\[Delta], 0, 2 \[Pi] 52000}], Frame -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Almost certainly your function has multiple minima. No fitting program can find the global minima without some help.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem of scaling! I changed

`wr->wr kHz, t->t \[Mu]s`

in the model.

No additional knowledge of parameter values is needed!

```
kHz = 1000;
\[Mu]s = 10^-6;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {((wr kHz)^2/ Sqrt[(wr kHz)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2])^2 Sin[1/2 Sqrt[(wr kHz)^2 + (\[Delta] + \[Delta]0)^2]t \[Mu]s]^2 }, \
{wr, \[Delta]0, t}, \[Delta], Method -> "NMinimize" ]

nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(*{wr -> 0.156335, \[Delta]0 -> -154768., t ->-80.7095}*)

Show[{ListPlot[data] , Plot[nlm[d], {d, 0,dmax}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Scaling is never inappropriate but it looks like this time the result landed on a local minimum as the root mean square (`nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5`) is 0.0755918 for what you did compared to the much lower value of 0.0417742 from @JulienKluge.

Comment: @JimB Scaling data  `dataS = Map[{#[[1]]/dmax, #[[2]]} &, data]` gives an improved fit `un = NonlinearModelFit[
  dataS, {a^2  b^2 Sinc[b Sqrt[a^2 + (dS + c)^2]]^2 }, {a, b, c}, dS ,
   Method -> "NMinimize" ]
` with  `un["EstimatedVariance"] (*0.0017*)`

Comment: Good.  That scaling seems to get the same parameter estimates (with the resulting same minimum estimated variance).  And it's a scaling based solely on the data (i.e., `dmax`) as opposed to "thinking" which isn't a bad thing either.

Comment: With  `dmax=data[[-1,1]]` the estiamted variance .0017 is much smaller than .04!?

Comment: In my comments I used the root mean square error (`nlm["EstimatedVariance"]^0.5`) rather than the estimated variance.  (I tend to use the root mean square error as it is in the same units as the response variable.)